how to generating thumbnail from HLS remote URL (*.m3u8) for android
I am looking to generate thumbnail for particular timeframe from HLS remote URL
for ex :  https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/img_bipbop_adv_example_ts/master.m3u8
I have tried MediaMetadataRetriever but it does not work for live streams (HLS)
any code snippet or library is appreciated, thanks

The FFmpeg library can extract a thumbnail from a particular video frame.
Use the following function to generate a thumbnail:
private fun generateThumbnailFromHls(url: String, timestamp: String, outputImage: String) {
        val command = arrayOf(
            "-i", url,
            "-ss", timestamp,
            "-vframes", "1",
            "-q:v", "2",
            "-y", outputImage
        )

        FFmpegKit.executeAsync(command.joinToString(" ")) { session ->
            val returnCode = session.returnCode
            if (returnCode.isValueSuccess) {
                Log.d("FFmpeg", "Thumbnail saved to $outputImage")
            } else {
                Log.e("FFmpeg", "Error occurred: ${session.failStackTrace}")
            }
        }
    }

Don't forget to add FFmpeg in your app: build.gradle

do you know how to generate thumbnail for the latest timeframe, instead of passing timestamp?

I got it, we have to use
val command = arrayOf(
"-sseof", "-1", "-i", url, "-frames:v", "1", "-y", outputImage
)
